# How can I make my ForegroundService to show notifications on Android 13?

Tags: java, android

My app was working fine until I used it on an Android 13 phone. On this phone, my ForegroundService doesn't display a notification as in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp6uu.jpg), but it's visible in the Foreground Services (FGS) Task Manager as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#handle-user-initiated-stop).

I put the [POST_NOTIFICATIONS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#POST_NOTIFICATIONS) permission in the manifest, but I still can't see the foreground notification and I need it visible at all times, as my app manages calls that I want to answer/reject/end from notifications.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

to make it work the same on Android 13, you need to ask for the POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission also at runtime! See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission) for the changes that came with Android 13.

Adding a `Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS` ALSO to your existing permissions request should solve the problem.